# How to save a a new excel file in Python

Tags: python

Open excel，then click file->New->Blank workbook, we can get a blank workbook. We can input some information.
I want to use Python to save the created Excel to the path we set.

```
import win32com.client
import os
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlsx_fullname = os.path.abspath("Book1")
workBook = excel.Workbooks.Open(xlsx_fullname)
excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro("FDSFORCERECALC(False)")
workBook.Save()
workBook.Close(True)
excel.Application.Quit()
```

I used this code, but I can't use python to select this excel file. It's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```py
xlsx_fullname = os.path.abspath("Book1")
workBook = excel.Workbooks.Open(xlsx_fullname)
...
workBook.Save()
```

to

```py
workBook = excel.ActiveWorkbook
...
workBook.SaveAs(Filename="c:/path/to/your desired filename.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you very much!You solved the problem I hadn't solved in three days！nb